# Cancel option for 'add comment' button on questions

Tags: feature-request, support, comments

There should be a cancel option for the 'add comment' button on questions.

It would be useful because otherwise one would have to hit page refresh to get it back to normal.

This is a change request and not an information request on how it can presently be done like [How can I cancel a comment during initial writing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51917/how-can-i-cancel-a-comment-during-initial-writing).

Comment: Just *hiding* the DIV again might *not* make browsers also [clear the contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495708/clear-form-button-in-html-do-we-really-need-this) of the text area. Next, clicking "add comment" again, might reveal the previous contents too. I guess that's more confusing (or maybe even evil) than not being able to hide it?

Comment: @Myzifer Sorry I didn't reply earlier (I did not get the @name notification). I wasn't the down-voter (didn't up-vote either) I made a huge type. I **DON'T** think it's SUCH a bad idea!! Sorry about that!! I deleted my comment to avoid further confusion! Again, Sorry.

Comment: I suggest not clicking it in the first place if you don't want it open.  Once you start down the path of adding a comment you may have to accept the very real possibility that you might end up with a text box you can trivially remove with one click using `F5`.  Developer time is limited, and I personally would rather have them add features that will be regularly used by thousands of people than adding features that will only be used by a tiny fraction of users.  Especially so when the feature simply replaces a single click action with another single click action.

Comment: @Pollyanna tell me when you go to edit a comment what options do you see? oh yes a "cancel" button pops up right next to where you clicked "Edit Comment" now there’s a reason a cancel button was put in there now wasn't there, I'd assume it to be along the lines of why there should be a cancel button for when you click add comment, it's all about consistency and having a better designed site. Also how many users does it take for something to be important 10? 100? 1000? etc who decides and how do you even know whether a tiny number of users will use it unless you know how many clicks the "Add

Comment: @Pollyanna Comment" button gets everyday and that turns out to be a low number which even then does that dismiss the problem/improvement just because a small number of users would use it, since even then the issue is still present just being ignored so I'd rather point out all and any time bug/improvement if it means it helps out the site in some way and then at least the site devs have a wider choice as to what they can work on.

Comment: This is a valid request, being duplicate does not mean it's bad, off topic, or invalid. But your request is 100% the same as the other one hence it's closed as duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars The other question was asking "how to cancel after adding a comment", my question is "can we make this change to handle cancelling comments".

They're asking for info on the issue, I'm suggesting a new solution.

I repeat I'm asking for something new they are not.

It's the same issue, but not the same request as we're asking different things.

Like "how to cook a pizza" vs "can you try cooking a pizza with explosives".

Or "how to descend a mountain", versus "can we add a ski slope to make descending quicker".

So again same topic but 100% diff request.

Comment: You are wrong, but looks like I can explain any better, sorry.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I'm not wrong, the other questions asks how to do it, I'm asking for a new way of doing it.

The answer to the other question is to explain how it's presently possible, the answer to my question is either implement the new options, place the change request in the backlog, or reject.

There answer can be responded to by anyone, mine is directed towards site designers.

Again it's not a duplicate.

Comment: At the time this was asked it is sufficiently close to be a duplicate, asked several months later. The proposed duplicate is also a feature request. --- With that said, with the recent edit, it's fair to re-ask a decade later. --- Voting to reopen; this rather than the other.

Comment: @Rob great now we have two same requests. Noise, clutter, and double work for staff it it's ever get done. Time has no meaning at all, it's not like the content is rotting over time.

Comment: @Sha, I knew it was you, from the first few words in the notification. Why does there have to be double the work, the other can be closed; two birds with one stone is a beneficial *double*, not twice the work.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want that, other than page aesthetics? Does it bother you much to have an open, empty comment box on the page now and then? I don't see that as a major problem.

Comment: Do all problems have to be major for anything to be done about it?
One shouldn't have to hit refresh to get rid of it and I don't see it as a difficult thing to fix.

Comment: At the very least now I hope the site admins would be aware of it in case they get the free time to fix it. Also if you notice when one edits a comment they have a cancel button so by that same logic when one adds a comment there should be a cancel button too.

Comment: @Myzifer: You have some good points. I assume even small problems can be fixed, if there's enough pressure for them. Until that happens (if it happens), probably your best bet would be to write a GreaseMonkey script which does that - look around Meta for examples, people have written various scripts to modify the look and behavior of the UI.

Comment: If I visit stackoverflow enough and notice it enough that it gets under my skin then I'll look into that but otherwise I'll just have my fingers crossed this question gets noticed.

Comment: "If I visit stackoverflow enough and notice it enough that it gets under my skin" - Interesting that it's not important enough for you to spend time on...

Comment: @Pollyanna wow that comment rly seems like you have something strong against me/this feature ofc I could be wrong since this is only text but anytime I've heard someone say something like that then that's usually the case, either way I'd like to point out that your missing the point of context of that reply, being that 1 I was a new member and wasn't sure how often I'd be using the site which now turned out to be daily, 2 I have enough on my plate since starting this new job which involves me already needing to learn a number of new prog lang so adding another unfamilar lang/program to that

Comment: @Pollyanna list just to solve 1 problem which doesn't just affect me so would be better if solved site wide instead of only on my client.