# UI bug: cannot close errant comment boxes, while editing others?

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to cancel a comment during initial writing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51917/how-to-cancel-a-comment-during-initial-writing)

(I moved this over here from Graphic Design Meta because I just noticed it's on SO, as well [Gasp!!])

Anytime you click "add comment," there is no option to cancel!

This bug showed up for me while I was attempting to edit a comment I just left.  I clicked "Add comment" when I meant to click "edit."  So it popped up an unclosable comment box.

I then, proceeded to choose edit, as I initially intended...
... and the comment box wouldn't die.  This left two comment boxes on the screen and it looked odd, to say the least.

pic below:

[Temporary Link (my job's firewall is annoying) (will link image properly, later)](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/FXaeSsiYTT-_fQciDMlPCQ?feat=directlink)

Again, this happens anytime on this site when you choose "add comment" and should be a relatively easy fix (possibly using the similar logic for canceling a comment edit).  As a user, I was thinking "oops, I didn't mean to click that, how do I undo this..." and it was odd to not have an option to do so.  You can even scroll down a page and click "add comment" everywhere, creating dozens of zombie comment boxes.

This is definitely a UI quirk...

Hopefully someone can fix these zombie comment boxes before they eat our brains.

Comment: @Jon: I'd argue that in the several (albeit minor) use cases where a user accidentally clicked "add comment" it's awkward to not be able to cancel that unintended action. Especially since other comment tasks allow cancelation (i.e. editing).

Comment: @Jon: definitely very similar. One nuance: I think it's a more jarring UI experience as pictured in the attached image, where you're editing one comment and the "add comment" box is still "alive." Especially when the box RIGHT ABOVE allows for cancellation... it's inconsistent, to say the least. In that situation, the user should expect to be able to cancel the bottom comment.

Comment: No argument there, but this is still a dupe. You can suggest an edit to add the image to that question if you want.

Comment: @Jon: Maybe, but I don't think that approach would draw attention to this issue.  Especially considering the post is nearly 1 year old.  I'd also argue it's not exactly a dupe, but that's debatable. My aim here is to get someone who cares to notice this issue and consider it. IMHO, suggesting an edit to add the image above won't further the goal of underscoring a subtle problem and helping make improvements. That's all I'm after.