# Pressing Esc when editing a comment should cancel editing

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, keyboard-shortcuts

When editing a post, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> does the same thing as clicking the "cancel" link: it cancels the edit. However, when editing a comment, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> does nothing.

Could pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> when editing a comment cancel that edit as well?

Comment: I can't take you seriously with a finger for a face.

Comment: [This is my similar feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one/109096#109096) for the SE keyboard shortcuts. Make sure it gets some attention if you like it to be implemented.

Comment: @slhck Upvoted.

Comment: *Love* the finger face. It looks really cool.

Comment: @JNK It could be worse. ;-)

Comment: @Pekka, is everything okay? (See my edit summary.)

Comment: Gah! A fellow Mac user asking for _more_ of the emacs-style keybindings to be invalidated on SO! Why?!

Comment: @Ἰησοῦς Escaping from Emacs-based keybindings is a noble goal.

Comment: LOL. typing :/ no way, -1.

Comment: @c69 I hope you realise that I am not advocating the removal of the ‘cancel’ link, and that recognising Esc would make editing comments similar to editing posts.

Comment: @Bavarious, yes - but that would still mean that, if a non-emacs user will need to type `Esc`  - he will cancel himself out of his comment.

Comment: @c69 Which would be consistent with the behaviour when editing a post. Are you saying that Esc shouldn’t be allowed in both cases?

Comment: @Bavarious: I don't think I could get by editing on SO without my trusty Meta-c, Meta-l, and Meta-u. There's Option-key equivalents for most other Meta key functions, but I've unlearnt them all over the past decade.

Comment: Actually, it looks like a double-Esc is required to cancel editing of a post. (I was wondering why I hadn't noticed this behavior before.) That would be perfectly fine for comments too.

Comment: @Ἰησοῦς Odd. Single Esc works for me when editing posts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe I have something weird in my DefaultKeyBinding.dict I don't even remember half the things I've tried to do in there...

Comment: @Pop you are so right, what was I thinking!

Comment: Keyboard power is the ultimate, so yeah. Sure, and I really doubt having this functionality annoys anybody. So yea, do it!

Answer (score 4):

A keyboard shortcut to cancel a comment does not make sense.

When you edit a post, canceling will ask for confirmation before you lose any changes. If you didn't make any changes, this convenient shortcut will quickly bring you back to the original screen.

But comments are created inline. If you didn't enter any text, there's nothing to jump back to. But if you *did* enter a comment, one slip of the finger will send your text to the great  **poof** in the sky. So we would have to add an *"are you sure"* confirmation. That doesn't make it much of a shortcut. Where's the upside?

Comment: Two situations: if I post a comment, then click edit, then decide not to edit it (which was the actual situation that led me to this request); and even if SO shows a confirmation dialog in case the comment has actually been edited, it’d still allow for keyboard-only cancelling of a comment edit. And I’m not sure what you mean by ‘there’s nothing to jump back to.’ There is an original screen to go back regardless of the editing operation being on a post or a comment… or maybe I’ve misunderstood something.

Comment: Not sure if it was added after this post, but there is now "cancel" link when editing comments. It send the changes you made to the great poof in the sky without any dialog to confirm. More than that: ENTER key is submitting the comment, even if pressed by mistake. Can you please reconsider?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That happens when you are editing a comment, not adding a comment. When writing a comment, you could accidentally hit the esc button (it happens to me when I try to add ` in a post), but it is rather difficult you click a link while writing a comment.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno it's true and makes some sense, however personally I still want to have ESCape cancel the comment, just used to that key canceling things. :)